# Как мне отправить formData и значение переменной одним запросом методом POST, используя fetch?

Tags: javascript, php

Моя задача, достать данные из формы используя **formData**, и затем отправить данные формы и переменную методом POST в php файл.
***Вот мой код:***

```
let formData = new FormData(form);
    if(error==0) { //проверка на правильность заполнения формы
        const descriptionСart = localStorage.getItem("derscription_cart");
        console.log(descriptionСart);
        const response = await fetch('./formSend.php', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: formData,
        });
        
        if(response.ok){
            let result = await response.json();
            console.log(result);
            // form.reset();
            alert("Ваш заказ отправлен успешно!");
        }
        else{
            alert("Ошибка");
        }
    }else{
        alert("Заполните обязательные поля и проверьте на наличие ошибок");
    }
```

А как мне используя этот запрос передать переменную descriptionCart (в этой переменной содержится обычная строка)?

Comment: Вам это нужно https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append ?

Comment: Спасибо, что быстро помогли!!!

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!